Remove async and await in method with await foreach
I would like to know if it is possible to remove the await from this method so as not to have an asynchronous method.
public static async Task Run(IMinioClient minio,
        string bucketName = "my-bucket-name",
        string prefix = null,
        bool recursive = true,
        bool versions = false)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running example for API: ListObjectsAsync");
            var listArgs = new ListObjectsArgs()
                .WithBucket(bucketName)
                .WithPrefix(prefix)
                .WithRecursive(recursive)
                .WithVersions(versions);
            await foreach (var item in minio.ListObjectsEnumAsync(listArgs).ConfigureAwait(false))
                Console.WriteLine($"Object: {item.Key}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Listed all objects in bucket {bucketName}\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Bucket]  Exception: {e}");
        }
    }

https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet/blob/master/Minio.Examples/Cases/ListObjects.cs
Thank you for your help.
Usually I do a .Result to do this but here the await is done on a foreach

You call ListObjectsEnumAsync. Is there also a method ListObjectsEnum, that returns IEnumerable instead of IAsyncEnumerable?

why would you use an async method such as ListObjectsEnumAsync, when you don't want to execute it asynchronously? What exactly do you want to achieve here? What should your funtion do with the list?

you need to rethink this; here's a relevant discussion - it isn't about .NET specifically, but is on async vs non-async methods (a topic that impacts many runtimes/languages) - https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ - async code is fundamentally different and you can't hand-wave away this and expose it in a non-async way

Minio Client, presumably just like any S3 compatible client for .Net you could use instead, is written around async. Why fight against it and not just use it?  Trying to use async stuff the sync way often ends up in hard to track down problems.

Also you linked the source just look at the previous check in of that file/method in git. It did not have Task in its signature. Maybe that version still works against an otherwise unchanged minio client.

XY problem?

You can use ToEnumerable() or ToBlockingEnumerable() to convert the asynchronous enumerable to an enumerable. See this answer.

You could use the .NET 7 API ToBlockingEnumerable:

Converts an IAsyncEnumerable<T> instance into an IEnumerable<T> that enumerates elements in a blocking manner.

Usage example:
public static void Run(IMinioClient minio,
    string bucketName = "my-bucket-name",
    string prefix = null,
    bool recursive = true,
    bool versions = false)
{
    var listArgs = new ListObjectsArgs()
        .WithBucket(bucketName)
        .WithPrefix(prefix)
        .WithRecursive(recursive)
        .WithVersions(versions);

    foreach (var item in minio.ListObjectsEnumAsync(listArgs).ToBlockingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Object: {item.Key}");
    }
}

This solution is susceptible to deadlocks, depending on the implementation of the ListObjectsEnumAsync method. Blocking on async code is inadvisable in general.

are you sure this specific solution is susceptible to deadlocks - nothing is mentioned in the docs and we are effectively "awaiting" by using the same infrastructure with the private ManualResetEventWithAwaiterSupport class

@IvanPetrov yes, I am pretty sure. If the ListObjectsEnumAsync is implemented with async/await, and there is at least one await without ConfigureAwait(false), and the code is invoked on the UI thread of a WinForms or WPF application, a deadlock is almost guaranteed.

It is quite strange to just not use asynchronous execution, when you can, but I will leave it up to you. Just be aware of risks of deadlocks and decreased performance.
If you really need to not use await, here's implementation without it. Bit verbose and not as clean as with awaits, but here it is.
First, let's define sample method returning IAsyncEnumerable:
public static class TestClass
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetIntsAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}

and the implementation without await would be:
var asyncEnumerator = TestClass.GetIntsAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();
try
{
    while (asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(asyncEnumerator.Current);
    }
}
finally
{
    asyncEnumerator?.DisposeAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

For conveniency you can define extension methods for such scenarios:
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T AwaitSynchornously<T>(this ValueTask<T> valueTask)
    {
        return valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static void AwaitSynchornously(this ValueTask valueTask)
    {
        valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static T[] LoopSynchronously<T>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable,
        Action<T> action)
    {
        return asyncEnumerable.EnumerateSynchronously(action).ToArray();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateSynchronously<T>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable,
        Action<T> action)
    {
        var asyncEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync().AwaitSynchornously())
            {
                action(asyncEnumerator.Current);
                yield return asyncEnumerator.Current;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            asyncEnumerator?.DisposeAsync().AwaitSynchornously();
        }
    }
}

Usage then is very simple:
TestClass.GetIntsAsync().LoopSynchronously(Console.WriteLine);


and using valueTask.AsTask() in a loop, even if it wouldn't deadlock, is going to lead to excessive GC allocations.

@Dai do you think it's possible to do without AsTask()?

I'd just make one extension method on IAsyncEnumerable without the Action

@Dai Your comment is valid, but OP specifically asked for such solution (alternative is to use Result, but it has the same risks). That's why i mentioned it is weir thing to do... I will update my answer with your suggestion, though i think OP is aware of risk he takes. Moreover, there is no way of wait sunchronously for ValueTask  without AsTask - again, this is needed to accomplish what OP needs. I leave the consideration for him

@IvanPetrov It was just example, I will leave up to OP to decide whether he needs to use Action or maybe a Func, or maybe nothing at all :)

@MichałTurczyn almost tempts me to post the answer that I wrote before seeing yours emerge :)
